# Http - How Are Parallel Connections Transmitted?

Tags: http, networking, browser

I'm taking a google video course about the http protocol. The http 1.1 introduced so called the pipeling technique to reduce a time between requestes and responses. There might occur the head of line blocking, so browsers uses parallel connections to avoid the HOL blocking.

I wonder, how does browsers send parallel network packets? I have never thought about possibility of multiple packets sent simultaneously, is it even possible to send parallel requests through a "cable"? How does it work?

Another thing is the http 2.0, does browsers implement parallel connections in this protocol? The http 2.0 uses the streams, but I'm not sure how browsers handles it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in HTTP is truly parallel. If multiple resources are to be tranferred at once, clients have to establish multiple connections. For HTTP/1.1, it is not uncommon to see three to five of these per host.

HTTP/2 is a bit different in that it can engage into interleaving: The smalest entity in HTTP/1.x is a *message* whereas in HTTP/2 this would be a *frame of a message*. This allows HTTP/2 to transmit multiple messages "at once" (really: one frame of a given message at a time) while HTTP/1.1 could just start pipelining and possible suffer from HOL-blocking as you mentioned.

As for your question regarding multiple packets being sent simultaneously: Yes, that is possible and is also regularly done. That would concern [wave physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_(physics)), [fourier transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), and electrical engineering and thus be a bit off-topic for SO ;)